# ndk-build file not found but is called

Tags: android, android-ndk, circleci, circleci-2.0

In circleci environment, calling ndk-build in console gives me the error :

```
/home/circleci/project/android-ndk-r10d/ndk-build: 158: 

/home/circleci/project/android-ndk-r10d/ndk-build: file: not found
```

but then it runs the ndk-build executable. I'm not sure what's the reason.

The ndk log is below:

```
NDK_LOG=1 ndk-build -n | grep HOST -C 5
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
/home/circleci/project/android-ndk-r10d/ndk-build: 158: /home/circleci/project/android-ndk-r10d/ndk-build: file: not found
HOST_ARCH=x86 (32-bit userland detected)
HOST_TAG=linux-x86 
GNUMAKE=/usr/bin/make (system path)
Android NDK: NDK installation path auto-detected: '/home/circleci/project/android-ndk-r10d'
Android NDK: GNU Make version 4.1 detected
Android NDK: Host OS was auto-detected: linux
Android NDK:  Host operating system detected: linux
/bin/sh: 1: file: not found
Android NDK: Host CPU was auto-detected: x86
Android NDK: HOST_TAG set to linux-x86
Android NDK: Host tools prebuilt directory not found
Android NDK: Host 'echo' tool: echo
Android NDK: Host 'echo -n' tool: printf %s
Android NDK: Host 'cmp' tool: cmp
Android NDK: Host 'awk' tool: awk
/home/circleci/project/android-ndk-r10d/build/core/build-local.mk:148: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
Exited with code 2
```

so to resolve the `"/bin/sh: 1: file: not found"` issue, I installed 'file using:

> sudo apt-get install -y file

but I still have the error:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
NDK_LOG=1 ndk-build -n | grep HOST -C 5
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_ARCH=x86 (32-bit userland detected)
HOST_TAG=linux-x86 
GNUMAKE=/usr/bin/make (system path)
Android NDK: NDK installation path auto-detected: '/home/circleci/project/android-ndk-r10d'
Android NDK: GNU Make version 4.1 detected
Android NDK: Host OS was auto-detected: linux
Android NDK:  Host operating system detected: linux
Android NDK: Host CPU was auto-detected: x86
Android NDK: HOST_TAG set to linux-x86
Android NDK: Host tools prebuilt directory not found
Android NDK: Host 'echo' tool: echo
Android NDK: Host 'echo -n' tool: printf %s
Android NDK: Host 'cmp' tool: cmp
Android NDK: Host 'awk' tool: awk
/home/circleci/project/android-ndk-r10d/build/core/build-local.mk:148: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
Exited with code 2
```

How do I resolve this

```
Android NDK: Host tools prebuilt directory not found
```